Is there a Backpack version 6 crud field method to deny access to create a new n-n relationship
I want to conditionally hide the + New Item button on a many to many relationship.
Is there a crud field method or attribute to perhaps deny acess to create relationships or otherwise hide the button depending on a model state.
Admins should still be able to edit or delete existing entries.

I don't think the exact relationship details are critical to the task but here are the highlights
The Eloquent relationship is userAllocations(): BelongsToMany and relates Centre and User and has additional pivot field for a valid until date
 CRUD::field('userAllocations')->type('relationship')
    ->subfields([
        [
            'name' => 'user',
            'ajax' => true,
            'attribute' => 'reverse_full_name',
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-9'],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'valid_date',
            'type' => 'date', 
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-3']
        ],
    ])


I think you best chance here will be play with JS
Since, in relationship is not create to fully control about access, you can try to do something like this in table field because you can deny new records setting the "max".
In relationship i guest you best chance will be hide the button using JS as you can load a script with:
Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/YOURSCRIPT.js');

Cheers.
